# Pandas: Update multiple rows using list

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to update pandas dataframe using list.

```
Dataframe with columns A, B, C

A B C
------
1 a F
2 b F
3 c F
4 d F
5 e F
```

I have 2 lists, one contains list of elements whose value needs to update from column `B` and second contains actual value to replace in column `C`.

Elements to update from column `B` names=['a', 'd', 'e']
Values to replace in column `C` values=['T', 'T', 'G']

```
Output after update

A B C
------
1 a T
2 b F
3 c F
4 d T
5 e G
```

How to update the dataframe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) combined with [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
names = ['a', 'd', 'e']
values = ['T', 'T', 'G']

m = df['B'].isin(names)
df.loc[m, 'C'] = df.loc[m, 'B'].map(dict(zip(names, values)))
```

Less efficient alternatives:

```
df['C'] = df['B'].map(dict(zip(names, values))).fillna(df['C'])

df['C'] = df['C'].mask(df['B'].isin(names), df['B'].map(dict(zip(names, values))))
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C
0  1  a  T
1  2  b  F
2  3  c  F
3  4  d  T
4  5  e  G
```

Comment: Hi mozway, Thanks for the quick reply. I am using the code from first section.Being newbie, It took me sometime to grasp the logic(vectorize). Earlier I was trying using `for` loop and was very slow. This very fast.